# Is it possible to use the information from a single cell in Google Sheets to automatically update the progress bar on a Squarespace website?

Tags: google-sheets, squarespace

I have a progress bar on my Squarespace website that is made with Bootstrap. I store sales information in a Google Sheet. On the site, I have a sales goal that I am trying to reach, so for the sake of example, $2000. I would like the progress bar to update based on the number that is in the Google Sheet. I already have the Google Sheet adding up all of the amounts and doing the math to determine the percentage, I just need that percentage to be displayed in the progress bar and to automatically update.

Essentially I want to make an in-house version of Kickstarter.

Comment: try SPARKLINE fx

Answer (score 1):

To automatically retrieve data from a Google Sheet you can use the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api), specifically you can use the [spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) method.

To access this API on your account you will also need to also create a GCP project to [set up OAuth access](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server) and build an app that connects to the API through this project.

I'm no expert on Squarespace, but while they do seem to have some [connection with Google Workspace](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206542057-Using-Google-Workspace-with-Squarespace), it seems limited to creating an account, not integrating their APIs, so you'll probably need to use their [developer platform](https://developers.squarespace.com/) to build the app yourself.

All in all, it will take some work and development hours to automate this. Unless you plan to extend your website's functionality in the future and include more of the Google APIs in it, you're probably better off manually updating this progress bar for the time being.